# Why is Outlook deleting messages as soon as I click on the folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I have three issues...I'm using Outlook 2003 on exchange.

1) My email stopped storing messages in sent items
2) When I click on sent items all of the old items that were stored before this problem started occurring do not appear arranged by date, it keeps changing back to arranged by "To".
3) When I click on the deleted items folder it clears the folder immediately without my telling it to.

Help

Comment: Check what your anti-virus / internet security is set to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any registry cleaning tools? Looks like your outlook installation is corrupted. Try reinstalling.